# Cannot instantiate the type Image java?

Tags: java, image, swing, embedded-resource, imageicon

```
public Image  images[] = new Image[20];

    for(i=0; i<10; i++){
images[i]=new Image(getClass().getResource("/images/"+i+".jpg"));
        }
```

I am trying to add images to array but it gives the error Cannot instantiate the type Image j

What can be the reason?

Comment: You can't directly instantiate an abstract class!

Answer (score 6):

Abstract classes cant be instantiated directly. You could use [`ImageIO.read`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#read%28java.net.URL%29) which returns `BufferedImage`, a sub-class of `Image`

```
void loadImages() throws IOException {

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        images[i] = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/images/" + i + ".jpg"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Multiple markers at this line
 - Unhandled exception type 
  IOException
 - Cannot instantiate the type 
  Image

Comment: `IOException` is a checked exception, which needs a try/catch block or thrown from the surrounding method as shown

Answer (score 4):

`Image` is an abstract class and thus cannot be instancied.
You should use one of the class who extend `Image`, like `BufferedImage` or `VolatileImage`.

Source: [Javadoc of Image](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Image.html)